# PyGame - Draw Line Based on Heading

Tags: python, math, trigonometry

I'm using `pygame.draw.line` to draw a line between two coordinates in pixels, the required format of this function is `(begin_x,begin_y),(end_x, end_y)`.

The begining coordinate for this line can be (0,0), and the line must have 100px of entire length. But which will be the ending coordinate for this line if the heading between the beggining and the end is 060º?

This line is the resultant vector of the airplane on screen.

Eg. If the airplane heading is 090º the ending coordinate is (0,100), if is 0º it would be (-100, 0), and so on.

```
# Tried this but it's not working
ending_x = begin_x + math.cos(heading) * length
ending_y = begin_y + math.sin(heading) * length
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend learning the basics of trigonometry to get started, for example https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trigonometry.html.

Here I've drawn a diagram with two points, `A` and `B`. `A` is the centre/starting point, and `B` is the coordinate you are trying to calculate.  The distance between these points is labelled `L`. I also draw the angle `a` that represents the heading between points `A` and `B`.

[image: Basic trigonometry diagram, labelling the various things that can be calculated]

By using this diagram and applying basic trigonometry, you arrive at the equations in the sticky-note. The vertical difference between points `A` and `B` is `h`, which can be calculated by `L * sin(a)`. Similarly, the horizontal difference between the points `w` can be calculated with `L * cos(a)`.

Be careful because depending on the angle `a`, it is likely that the coordinates will not be integer values, so you may need to do some rounding or approximation.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Now Works
ending_x = begin_x + math.cos(math.radians(heading)) * length
ending_y = begin_y + math.sin(math.radians(heading)) * length
```

Forgot to transform to radians.